# Rails Drop Down List Sort Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, activerecord

I have an array that is populating a dropdown list in a view (erb) file. I want to have the values in the dropdown list sorted by values (it's a list of names Last, First... just want them sorted by last). This is what I have:

```ruby
    <% 
  if @users
    users_arr = []
    @users.each do |u| 
      users_arr << ["#{u.name}", u.id]

    end
  end

  first_selected_parent = @kid.users && @kid.users.first ? @kid.users.first.id : ""
  second_selected_parent = @kid.users && @kid.users.count > 1 ? @kid.users.last.id : ""
%>
```

I've googled and tried a number of things but haven't been able to figure it out yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using an array here? Use the built-in `ActiveRecord::Collection` objects, which are almost like arrays but can use all the ActiveRecord methods. This code:

```ruby
User.all.order(:last_name => :desc)
```

grabs all your `User` records, and sorts them by the `last_name` field in descending order. You can iterate over the result using `.each`:

```ruby
@users = User.all.order(:last_name => :desc)
@users.each do |user|
  # do stuff
end
```

---

If you're trying to populate an HTML `<select>` element as part of a form, skip all the strange array manipulations and use Rails' form helpers:

```ruby
<%= form_for @resource, url: form_submission_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :field_name, options_for_select(User.all.order(:last_name => :desc).map{|u| [u.last_name, u.id]}) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly I'm trying to edit code someone else developed. I'm wondering if it is because the selection of the drop down box is then submitted along with a form that updates the database. I realized I left this part of the code out in my first post:

Comment: @PeterFulton I assume you're trying to populate an HTML `<select>` element here?

Comment: @PeterFulton In that case, instead of all the arrays, use existing form helpers. I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to use the `sort` method:
    users_arr.sort

This will return an array sorted on the first element of each entry.

```
irb(main):129:0> users_arr
=> [["Watson", 1], ["Olson", 2], ["Peters", 3], ["Warren", 4]]
irb(main):130:0> users_arr.sort
=> [["Olson", 2], ["Peters", 3], ["Warren", 4], ["Watson", 1]]
```

You can use `sort!` to sort the array in place, or `sort` (without the ! character) to produce a new (sorted) array.

The full syntax (for example, to sort on the second element of each entry) would use the `<=>` operator:

```
irb(main):132:0> users_arr
=> [["Olson", 2], ["Peters", 3], ["Warren", 4], ["Watson", 1]]
irb(main):133:0> users_arr.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
=> [["Watson", 1], ["Olson", 2], ["Peters", 3], ["Warren", 4]]
```